# How to color surface with stronger contrast

Tags: python, matlab, plot

In Matlab, I am trying to plot a function on 2-dim Euclidean space with following code

```
s=.05;
x=[-2:s:2+s];
y=[-1:s:3+s];
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
Z=(1.-X).^2 + 100.*(Y-X.*X).^2;
surf(X,Y,Z)
colormap jet
```

Here is what my plot look like:

[image]

I hope to color the surface with stronger contrast, just as [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rosenbrock_function.svg) shows
[image]

The plot in Wikipedia is drawn with Python code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig, azim = -128, elev = 43)
s = .05
X = np.arange(-2, 2.+s, s)
Y = np.arange(-1, 3.+s, s)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
Z = (1.-X)**2 + 100.*(Y-X*X)**2
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride = 1, cstride = 1, norm = LogNorm(), cmap = cm.jet)

plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")

plt.show()
```

My Matlab code and the Wikipedia Python code seem to both use "jet" as colormap, but their actual mappings of height value to color are different. So I was wondering how I can get similar coloring in Matlab?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve a similar appearance by:

- Setting the [`'EdgeColor'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.surface-properties.html#property_d119e930164) of the surface object to `'none'` to remove edge coloring.
- Modifying the [`'CData'` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.surface-properties.html#property_d119e931462) of the surface to mimic the [log-scaling of the color data](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/colors_api.html#matplotlib.colors.LogNorm) in the Python code.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```matlab
s = .05;
x = [-2:s:2+s];
y = [-1:s:3+s];
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
Z = (1.-X).^2 + 100.*(Y-X.*X).^2;
minZ = min(Z(:));  % Find minimum value of Z
maxZ = max(Z(:));  % Find maximum value of Z
C = minZ+(maxZ-minZ).*log(1+Z-minZ)./log(1+maxZ-minZ);  % Create a log-scaled
                                                        %   set of color data
surf(X, Y, Z, C, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
colormap jet
```

And here's the resulting plot:

[image]

### How the log-scaling works...

The log-scaled `Z` data which is used to produce the color data `C` causes the red-orange range of the jet color map to be used by more surface points, improving the contrast for this particular surface. The way this works can be visualized with this simple example:

```matlab
x = 0:5:100;        % Create a range of values from 0 to 100
plot(x, x, 'b-*');  % Plot the values as a straight line (y = x) in blue
hold on;            % Add to the plot
plot(x, 100.*log(1+x)./log(101), 'r-*');  % Plot a log-scaled version of x in red
colorbar            % Display the default jet color map, for comparison
```

[image]

The original blue points are evenly distributed across the range of colors they correspond to in the color bar on the right. When log-scaled, these points are shifted upward to the red line. Notice how this results in a reduced density of points in the lower blue-green range and an increased density of points in the red-orange range.

### Getting better contrast in general...

For the particular surface used here log-scaling of the color data helps use a greater range of the color map across all the points on the surface. Since there are many points at lower height (i.e. color index) values, the log-scaling spreads these low points out more to use a wider range of colors in the large trough of the surface.

However, if you want to improve the contrast for an arbitrary surface by making better use of the range of your color map, log-scaling won't always work. A general solution that may work better is to sort all of the height values for your surface in ascending order, then map these to a linear range that spans your entire color map. Here's what you would get if you do this for your above surface:

```matlab
C = Z;
[~, index] = sort(C(:));
C(index) = 1:numel(index);
h = surf(X, Y, Z, C, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
colormap jet
caxis([1 numel(index)]);
```

[image]

This should generally give better contrast than the `C = Z` default surface coloring.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks! I was wondering what is the rationale of obtaining color data C from height data Z in your Matlab script? How do you know it is the one used for color normalization in the Python script?

Comment: @Tim: With MATLAB (and this appears to be the same for Python) a 3-D surface will be plotted by default using the values in the Z data to determine the coloring of the surface. If you don't want this default coloring, you can instead supply your own color data, which could be a scaled version of the height data Z or even a [texture-mapped image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/visualize/f0-18164.html#f0-9250). It appears that Python gives you the option of applying a normalizing function in the call to `plot_surface`, whereas you have to apply this to the data yourself in MATLAB.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks! I would like to know why "C = maxZ.*log(1+Z)./log(1+maxZ); " can make the coloring have strong contrast? How do you know it is the way used by "norm = LogNorm()" in the Python script?

Comment: @Tim: I don't know *exactly* how `LogNorm` in Python does it, but in general if you take the log of a range of numbers greater than 1 then the larger numbers get scaled down much more strongly than the smaller numbers do. For example, `log(10) = 2.3026` while `log(1000) = 6.9078`. This means that larger values of Z become much smaller values in C, which when used as indices into the jet colormap cause the reddish-orange range to be stretched a great deal. You can visualize this by doing `surf(X,Y,C);` and noting how the larger values fall of much more slowly.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks! So when using values in C instead of in Z as indices into jet colormap, isn't that the indices become closer and the colors they index also closer? Why the effect is on the contrary, the colors get spread out?

Comment: @Tim: I added an example to my answer illustrating how the log-scaling works. Hopefully it will clear things up a bit.

Comment: @gnovice: Thanks! so log scaling is useful only for coloring points of particular clustering pattern, i.e. the majority have relatively small values? How about the opposite case when the majority have relatively large values, how to shift them down? And how about when the majority are all in a narrow range, whether the range is in the middle or somewhere else?

Comment: @Tim: Since the log-scaling solution is somewhat specific to this particular surface, I edited my answer to add a more general way to improve color contrast on a given surface.

Answer (score 1):

Straight out of the help page for colormap:

> Files in the color folder generate a number of colormaps. Each file accepts the colormap size as an argument. For example,
>
> colormap(hsv(128))
> creates an hsv colormap with 128 colors. If you do not specify a size, a colormap the same size as the current colormap is created.

I've used this feature to change the range of colors to make a better use of the available spectrum.