# Octave/Matlab: Colormap not based on height

Tags: matlab, 3d, octave, figure, colormap

When I plot several functions in a 3D figure (using `surf(my_function)`) the default is that it colors each little bit of the function surface in a way that the color corresponds to the height at that point.

I would like to change that a little bit. I have several functions I want to plot on the same figure, and most of them are separated a little bit in the z direction, so they have different colors (a low one has shades of blue, a high one has shades of red). I would like to keep that for the most part, except have the function surface be different shades of the same color, but have that color change on each iteration of the loop I have for plotting these functions.

In my specific case, I'm plotting the wave functions of a particle in a 2D square well (infinite potential well). However, as some energy levels (that is, the height `z`) are degenerate I have different wave functions occupying the same `z`. I want to distinguish them by their shade of color, while retaining the method that low valleys of the function are a certain shade while high valleys are a different shade of the same color.

Comment: `surf(your_function,your_chosen_colors)`

Comment: Read more: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/coloring-mesh-and-surface-plots.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to color surface with stronger contrast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073865/how-to-color-surface-with-stronger-contrast)

Comment: Now I've ran into a problem. I tested the generic surface colormap on the `surf(peaks)` function and it looks normal. But when I try to add in the colormap argument `surf(peaks,jet)` the colors are random and do not depend on z.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the color for `surf` independently: This shows a height from peaks and color from sombrero (don't rely on `__osmesa_print__`, it's an internal Octave function):

```
figure ("visible", "off")
surf (peaks(64), sombrero (64));
[az, el] = view ();
n = 1;
clear img_stack;
for nel = el:2:90
  view (az, nel);
  drawnow;
  img_stack (:, :, :, n++) = __osmesa_print__ (gcf);
endfor
imwrite (img_stack, "out.gif", "DelayTime", 0.1, "Compression", "lzw")
```

[image: peaks with sombreo color, elevation goes from 30° to 90°]